# Android setting fragment toolbar title

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, toolbar

I was having some minor bug with fragment transaction. The problem occurs when I opened up more than one fragment and press the back button and the title shown on toolbar is wrong.

For instance, from my `Home -> Expenses fragment`, and I press back button from Expenses fragment, the title shown on toolbar is correct.

However, let's say `Home -> Expenses -> Incomes fragment`, and I press back button from Incomes fragment, it will go back to Home fragment, but the title shown on toolbar will be 'Expenses' instead of 'Home'.

Here is my set up for MainActivity which extends AppCompatActivity:

```
 // inside onCreate() put all these code
//Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                case R.id.home:
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                    return true;

                case R.id.expenses:
                    return true;

                case R.id.incomes:
                    return true;

                case R.id.history:
                    return true;

                case R.id.setting:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Then inside each of my fragments which extends Fragment, I set the title and override the back button:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expense,container,false);

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Expenses");
    // override on back key pressed back to main fragment
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

I even added this line `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");` to set the title when back button is on click but it is futile.

Comment: Any ideas? Is my question not clear?

Comment: Why do you handle back button pressing this way?

Comment: I found it online and it goes back to my main fragment directly.

Comment: Try it this way:
1. In your activity override onBackPress this way:     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }

    }

2. Remove the KeyListener of the fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way: 1. In your activity override onBackPress:

```
 @Override public void onBackPressed() {
     if (count == 0) { 
         super.onBackPressed(); 
     }
    else {
         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); 
    }
 }
```

2. Remove the KeyListener of the fragment.

Comment: It told me method does not override method from its superclass error message

Comment: In your activity?

Comment: I actually extends from Fragment

Comment: Yeah i know, but you should override onBackPress method in your activity which has the fragments in it.

Comment: Sorry but you mean the main fragment? But the toolbar title is still not right in the case I mentioned above

Comment: No, you must have an AppCompatActivity, maybe MainActivity? That one containts the fragments.

Comment: Yes I inserted it at the correct place but the toolbar title error I mentioned above still persist. Let's say I go from Home -> Expenses -> Income, when I press back button, it is now Income -> Expenses -> Home but when I reached the Home, the toolbar title is still showing Expenses

Comment: Did you remove the KeyListener from the fragments?

Comment: Yes I did, I followed what you said. But when I reach the MainActivity which contains all the fragment, the title is not set to Home

Comment: In mainfragment's onCreateView method do you set the toolbar title to Home?

Comment: Yes I did, I put this line: getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home"); inside onCreate()

Comment: Put it inside onCreateView instead of onCreate()

Comment: I don't have onCreateView inside MainActivity. MainActivity is extending from AppCompatActivity with navigation drawer for all the fragments

Comment: *Put it inside onCreateView instead of onCreate() in your HomeFragment

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("fragment title");
Just put this line in onCreateView() fragment.

and don't override back button in fragment override it in activity.

Comment: So you mean I should put the onKey in MainActivity rather than all the fragments onCreateView()?